# My ADB is not working in my android studio after changing my OS

Tags: android

I am new to android. I use my phone to run the android projects instead of emulator since I was familiar with phone from the beginning.

So my problem is ADB does not show my device. I don't know why. I was using windows 10 before and ADB worked well. Due to some reasons I changed to windows 7 yesterday. So the problem arises.

When I try to install the ADB it is not showing my device name. Not only my device, I tried with some other mobiles too. The problem exists. Please help me if someone have experienced the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: You need to install the drivers for your phone - for example if you havea Samsung phone you need to install the Samsung drivers.  Obviously Windows 10 shipped with the drivers and Windows 7 did not.  If you edit the question and say what kind of phone it is someone may be able to help.

Comment: thanks but it is working now thanks stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the following software: http://pdanet.co/a/
It made the trick for me. Not sure why it worked, but it worked ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Happy coding.